# SQl to list rows if not in another table

Tags: t-sql, sql

I have the following query which have 1000 rows

```
select 
staffdiscountstartdate,datediff(day,groupstartdate,staffdiscountstartdate),
EmployeeID 
from tblEmployees 
where GroupStartDate < '20100301' and StaffDiscountStartDate > '20100301' 
and datediff(day,groupstartdate,staffdiscountstartdate)>1 
order by staffdiscountstartdate desc
```

i have the following query which have 400 rows: ie the employees in tblemployees and in tblcards

```
select a.employeeid,b.employeeid 
from tblEmployees a,tblCards b 
where GroupStartDate < '20100301' 
and StaffDiscountStartDate > '20100301' 
and datediff(day,groupstartdate,staffdiscountstartdate)>1 
and a.employeeid=b.employeeid
```

How to list the employees which is there in tblemployees and not in tblcards?

ie is 1000-400 = 600 rows ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
    a.employeeid,
    b.employeeid 
from 
    tblEmployees a
        left join
    tblCards b 
        on
            a.employeeid=b.employeeid 
where 
    GroupStartDate < '20100301' 
and 
    StaffDiscountStartDate > '20100301' 
and 
    datediff(day,groupstartdate,staffdiscountstartdate)>1 
and
    b.employeeid is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a left join to join the tables and then filter where table tblCards is null.

```
select  
    a.employeeid 
from  
    tblEmployees a
left outer join
    tblCards b
on
    a.employeeid=b.employeeid
where  
    GroupStartDate < '20100301'  
and  
    StaffDiscountStartDate > '20100301'  
and  
    datediff(day,groupstartdate,staffdiscountstartdate)>1  
and  
    b.employeeid IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to list the employees which is
>   there in tblemployees and not in
>   tblcards?

```
select employeeid from tblEmployees 
   where employeeid not in 
   (select employeeid from tblCards)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 SELECT emp.EmployeeID
 FROM   tblEmployees AS emp
      LEFT JOIN tblCards AS crd ON (emp.EmployeeID = crd.EmployeeID)
 WHERE  (crd.EmployeeID IS NULL)
```